# Why onCreateView on my RecyclerView Adapter is not called?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I have a `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView`. And in my `onBind()` method in `recyclerView1` i am trying to set the data for `recyclerView2` , the fact is that `recyclerView1` has a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and `recyclerView2` has a custom `RecyclerAdapter` and the `onCreate()` method in `recyclerView2`'s `adapter` is never called , so the data set is good but it doesn't create my `recyclerView2` in the interface this recycler is empty.

I put a breakpoint on the `OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder` and it just skips this .

Here is the code from the `recyclerView2`'s `adapter` `onCreate` and `onBind` methods :

```
 adapterReceivedCommands = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comanda, ReceivedCommandsViewHolder>(optionsReceivedCommands) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ReceivedCommandsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_command,parent,false);
            layoutManagerOrder = new GridLayoutManager(parent.getContext(),3);
            orderRecycler = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_recycler);
            orderRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOrder);
            fragmentItem = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
            return new ReceivedCommandsViewHolder(itemView);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ReceivedCommandsViewHolder receivedCommandsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final Comanda comanda) {


            receivedCommandsViewHolder.tableNmb.setText(comanda.getmasa());
            orderModelArrayList = comanda.getcomanda();
            mAdaptor = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, orderModelArrayList);
            receivedCommandsViewHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaptor);
        }


    };
    adapterReceivedCommands.startListening();
    receivedCommandsRecycler.setAdapter(adapterReceivedCommands);

    return view;
}
```

And here is the code from the custom `recyclerView2`'s `adapter` :

```
 public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<OrderModel> orderModels = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comanda, ReceivedCommandsViewHolder> context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comanda, ReceivedCommandsViewHolder> context, ArrayList<OrderModel> orderModels) {
    this.orderModels = orderModels;
   this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_order,parent,false);
    OrderViewHolder holder = new OrderViewHolder(view);


    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, int position) {
    OrderModel curentModel = orderModels.get(position);
            holder.cantitateTxt.setText(curentModel.getCantitate().toString());
            holder.comandaTxt.setText(curentModel.getDenumireProdus());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item count is zero:

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

So `RecyclerView` doesn't see any items to inflate.  You should fix it to return the size of your list:

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return orderModels.size();
}
```